# Parsear JSON a Java

Tags: java, json, parsear

Hola soy medio nuevo en esto y estoy intentando parsear JSON a Java les dejo lo que he podido hacer intentando ver algunos tutoriales etc pero aún no me queda claro como obtener los datos, los json son de Riot etc, aun no puedo descifrar esto de parsear, aunque parezca simple.

el JSOn

```
{
   "type":"summoner",
   "version":"10.4.1",
   "data":{
      "SummonerBarrier":{
         "id":"SummonerBarrier",
         "name":"Barrera",
         "description":"Protege a tu campeón contra 115 a 455 de daño (según el nivel de tu campeón) durante 2 seg.",
         "tooltip":"Protege temporalmente contra {{ f1 }} de daño a tu campeón durante 2 seg.",
         "maxrank":1,
      }
```

El JSON es mucho mas largo pero sigue de la misma manera.Me lanza este error, al parecer algo estoy haciendo mal y no se que es si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.main.main(main.java:17)
```

El codigo de la clase main es este:

```
  package com.example;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             String json = "summoner.json";
             Gson gson = new Gson();
            Data prueba = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);      
            SummonerBarrier smite=prueba.getSummonerBarrier();
            System.out.println("El hechizo se llama: "+smite.getName());



    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la `línea 17` que refiere el error? En cuanto al JSON debes obtenerlo de alguna fuente o archivo, al parece aquí tu JSON sería esta cadena sin más: `summoner.json`

Comment: La linea 17 seria el println , con respecto a el json lo tuve que acortar en la publicacion directamente a summoner.json ya que me decia que era demasiado codigo, este es el json completo aunque es la version en ingles http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.4.1/data/en_US/summoner.json

Comment: O sea, que en `String json` recuperas el JSON real, ¿cierto? Debes decirlo con claridad porque viendo el código se interpreta que lo que quieres parsear es la cadena `summoner.json`.  Por otra parte, este tipo de manejos deben hacerse dentro de un bloque `try ... catch`

Comment: Si sería de esa manera, perdón por la falta de claridad es que lo había aclarado al momento de hacer la publicación pero me decia que era demasiado codigo al borrar codigo también borre las aclaraciones :p con respecto al try catch como he dicho soy nuevo en esto :c

Comment: Además, viendo el JSON del enlace, parece que el objeto que necesitas mapear se encuentra dentro de la clave `data` del JSON. Generalmente lo correcto sería tener un objeto superior que contenga además como miembro un objeto del tipo `Data`, haciendo el mapeo hacia ese objeto de jerarquía superior a `Data` y que por tanto la contiene. Si no tienes que obtener el JSON que hay en la clave `data` del JSON y hacer el mapeo en base a ese objeto. Parece que tu modelo de datos no está refinado en ese sentido ni 100% en sintonía con la realidad de los datos. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Estoy bastante restringido con respecto a publicar cada clase del JSON en stackoverflow, con respecto al objeto de tipo Data lo tengo, todas las clases del Json las genere con http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ y con respecto a mapear en base a el objeto data no te referis a la linea   Data prueba = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);

Comment: Si observas el JSON, tiene varias propiedades: `type`, `version` y `data`. El tipo de mapeo que intentas aquí: `Data prueba = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class); ` **asume que estás dentro de la propiedad `data` del JSON, pero no lo estás, estás dentro de otro objeto** y una de las propiedades de ese objeto es `data`. No sé si me logras entender. Si tú copias el JSON y generas una clase en  jsonschema2pojo.org verás que no se genera una clase `Data` solamente, sino otra clase y esa clase contendrá una propiedad del tipo `Data`. Significa que en tu modelo debería haber una clase superior a `Data`

Comment: Ah ya la encontre, la clase a la que te refieres tiene como atributos a type, version y data junto a sus respectivos get y set  lo cambie en el main con "Example prueba=gson.fromJson(json,Example.class) y creando un objeto de tipo Data data=prueba.getData() pero aun sigue insistiendo el error, talvez no estoy comprendiendo bien el tema de los json

Comment: Lo resolvi! muchas gracias A. Cedano, me ayudaste mucho con las dudas y lo entendi mejor, el error estaba por otro lado habia borrado yo mismo los contenidos de data " arroba" SerializedName("SummonerBarrier")
    "arroba" Expose" pensando que solo eran simples comentarios (error mio ya que estoy acostumbrado a los "arroba"param de las descripciones, y los @SerializedName etc no los habia visto todavia en mis clases de java) mil disculpas y muchas gracias! funciona a la perfeccion ahora :D

Answer (score 0):

encuentro dos situaciones que son incorrectas.

1-

> Data prueba = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);

la variable json únicamente contiene un nombre de archivo no un path completo para acceder al archivo.

2-

> Data prueba = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);

no puedes pasar un archivo o path completo a la funcion  `gson.fromJson()` asi nada mas
antes debes leer y cargar el archivo y pasarlo como parametro a dicha funcion.

```
 String json = "C:\\path_to_file\\summoner.json";

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(json));

Gson gson = new Gson();
Data prueba = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader , Data.class);
```

u otra forma podria ser  meter el contenido de tu JSON en la variable  :

`json`

```
         String json = "{variable:valor}";
         Gson gson = new Gson();
        Data prueba = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);      
        SummonerBarrier smite=prueba.getSummonerBarrier();
        System.out.println("El hechizo se llama: "+smite.getName());
```